# How to catch errors when copying files in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, copy, cp, file-copying, fileutils

I copy a file like this:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.copy(source_file, dest_file)
```

I would like to know if this operation succeeded, and if not, what was the error.

Where could I find the exceptions that can be thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is [not documented](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp), you have to check the source.